# Returning Print Layout to its default state in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, printing, default

When I first open Print Layout it has a set of panels on the right hand side - "Item Properties", "Atlas Generation", "Composition". For better or worse, these are easily configurable, so you can delete them or add them back in different places. For me this was too easy, because now I've lost panels I need and others are put in places where it's very hard to access them.
If I just quit Print Layout and open up a new one, it seems to have inherited the layout of panels from my previous Print Layout, in which I had screwed it up completely.

Is there some way I can return the configuration of the Print Layout panels to its default state, the one I started with and which most tutorials have?

Comment: For the missing panels did you try right clicking on a toolbar in the layout window and turning on the panels you want?  Did you click and hold on the panels you want to move and then moved them into a position you wanted?  If all else fails and you don't have a lot of customizations you can always rename your app profiles folder when QGIS is closed and then reopen QGIS. 
 C:\Users\yourusernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default

Answer (score 2):

Available in QGIS 3.32, maybe earlier.

Navigate to the "View" toolbar in the top left.

View -> Panel -> Item Properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the panel where the Item Properties should be and check the box next to Item Properties and everything will return to its place.